# How to get rating value for particular review?

Tags: magento2.3

I need to rating value for particular review which is given by add review.

Like if there are 5 customers given rating like 4,5,2,1.

I need that percentage value from Review Id.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use $reviewFactory via ObjectManager (not the best solution)

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$reviewFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Review\Model\Review');
$storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
$reviewFactory->getEntitySummary($product, $storeId);
$ratingSummary = $product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();
```

Comment: Thank you, Madam. But this code display particular product average rating value. I need a particular review's rating value.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code in your block class:

```
<?php
...
...

protected $ratingOption;
...
...
public function __construct(\Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context, \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Rating\Option\Vote\Collection $ratingOption) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->ratingOption = $ratingOption;
}
```

**Update 1:**

Then call this code in your function. Let us say the function name is **getRatingFromReviewId**. So the function would look like this:

```
public function getRatingFromReviewId($reviewId) {
    $ratingCollection = $this->ratingOption
                             ->addRatingInfo()
                             ->addOptionInfo()
                             ->addRatingOptions()
                             ->addFieldToFilter('review_id', $reviewId);
    return $ratingCollection;
}
```

Now in your PHTML file, your code should be like:

```
$reviewId = 3;
$ratings = $block->getRatingFromReviewId($reviewId);
if(count($ratings)) {
    foreach($ratings as $rating) {
        ...
        YOUR CODE to calculate the AGGREGATE OF ALL RATINGS
        ...
    }
}
```

This will give you the percentage value of each rating criteria (i.e. price, quality, etc.)

You can use this info to get the aggregate value of all ratings.

I hope it makes sense to you.

Comment: yes its ok but i want to display in any phtml file so let me know sir.

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel, I have updated my answer.

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel, did my answer help you?

Comment: actually I want not to display through the block. I want to display directly in .phtml file. Thank you,  sir.